# How to broadcast the rtmp live video using wowza media server?

Tags: android, media, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I have used javacv library to stream the live video from mobile to wowza media server and it's working fine. And I tried to record the live video in media server for broadcasting the video to multiple devices but I can hear only audio from the recorded video file.

Please let me know where I have done wrong and let me know the steps for re-stream the video to multiple device. I'm new to the Media server platform.

Thanks.

Comment: When you publish to Wowza and record, is there any indication in the logs of a problem? Which mechanism are you using to record the stream?

Comment: If you can shared wowza access and error logs, it will be useful for analysis.